# What kind of plants are these?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I got these plants at a nursery but I can’t figure out what they are called so I can take care of them properly.

The leaves are green and stiff the the stem has a red tint

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 1):

It is a variegated Ficus Elastica, often called a rubber tree or a rubber plant.

Although they look really different than their Ficus tree cousins, they are still a member of the Ficus family and are just as fussy as their cousins.

These plants like bright light, with little direct sunlight. You should water the plant when the top 1-2 inches of soil feels dry to the touch. Wipe the leaves with a damp cloth about once a week to remove any dust or dirt on the leaves.

Like most Ficus plants, they will drop their leaves in response to over or under watering, changes in light, being exposed to drafts or any sudden changes.

** Be aware, this plant is considered poisonous to dogs and cats **